# If X is the empty set, is there an element in X which is False? (for a Proposition P)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Course notes says:

If there was an element in X, such that P is true, that would imply that there was some t in X for which P is true and particularly that it would imply the existence of some t in X.

However X is the empty set, so no such t can exist. Hence, whatever the truth value of P, P is false.

This confuses me since it feels like the argument could be run in reverse for False:

If there was an element in X, such that P is FALSE, that would imply that there was some t in X for which P is FALSE and particularly that it would imply the existence of some t in X.

However X is the empty set, so no such t can exist. Hence, whatever the truth value of P, P is TRUE.

So the question seems to boil down to - if we can assign a truth value (rather than saying it is unknowable), then whether it is True or False implies there are some elements for which it is True or False. If there were no elements (as in the empty set) then it is neither True nor False.

It sounds naiive even to me. I guess the value of "False" is also stand-in for: does not exist.

Any pointers, reading materials or clarifications would be welcomed. Have I correctly identified my own misunderstanding here?

Comment: Is $P$ a simple proposition (no variable in it), or a truth function depending on a variable $t$ as in $P(t)$?

Comment: $\forall t\in \emptyset \colon P(t)$ is true, as is $\forall t\in \emptyset \colon \neg P(t)$.

Comment: @coffeemath I think it's a truth function depending on a variable t ... but we're talking about a set where there are no elements.. so maybe it doesn't matter? That's my rationalisation but in any case the Notes just used P here so I did the same. I didn't really appreciate there WAS a difference in all honesty

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "What about ∀x ∈ X,P? Well, let’s show that this must always be true. Indeed, its logical negation is ∃x ∈ X,¬P, and this is definitely false by argument in the previous paragraph. Hence ∀x ∈ X, P ." I copied and pasted that from the Notes. Does that square with what you wrote?

Comment: Sully-- I agree with your comment that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, as has been pointed out in comments under your post. Assuming that $P$, or rather $P(t)$, is a proposition about the elements of a set, your question can still mean several different things.

- A proposition $P(t)$ itself has no truth value, exactly because there's a variable in it.
- The statement "$\forall t\in\varnothing: P(t)$" is true regardless of what $P$ is. Sometimes we say that it's *vacuously* true. There reason is that since there are no counterexamples to refute it, we can't make it false, so it's true.
- The statement "$\exists t\in\varnothing: P(t)$" is false regardless of what $P$ is. To satisfy this statement, we must provide an actual element of the underlying set that creates a true statement. If we can't find such an element $t$ (for whatever reason), the claim of existence is false.

Comment: So this is a convention? An Axiom? Does it come from some prior piece of logic/information/convention ? For example, there are no counterexamples to refute that the first statement is false ... but we don't say it is False. Why go one way but not the other?

Comment: @SullyH: It's more like the [Law of the Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). The negation of "$\forall t: P(t)$" is "$\exists t: \neg P(t)$". When our domain of discourse is the empty set, the latter statement is false because we can't find such an element $t\in\varnothing$ to make $\neg P(t)$ true. And when the negation of a statement is false, the original statement has to be true.

Comment: @SullyH: And for the same reason, a statement would be false if and only if its negation is true. But we can't make "$\exists t\in\varnothing : \neg P(t)$" true.

Answer (score 1):

A note about your objection: when you say that $x\in\emptyset$ is always false, you do not mean" object $x$ that is in the empty set is false". You mean that, whatever object you consider, this object, or rather, the name of this object ( when substituted for the variable $x$) will never turn the open sentence into a true one. The particular reason , *here*, is that, whenever you replace $x$ by the name of an object, you get a contradiction. ( Which means that the sentence is not factually false, but necessarily false).

Apparently, your objection relies on this fallacy :

(1) it is false there is an $x$ that belongs to the empty set

(2) therefore, there is an $x$ that does not belong to the empty set

(3) therefore , there is a non-existing $x$ belonging to the emptyset

(4) therefore, there is an $x$ (belonging to the emptyset) about which I am talking.

---

- $P(t)$ by itself is an open sentence , not yet a sentence endowed with a truth value.
- By quantifying over $t$ , it will gain a truth value.
- First consider : $\exists (t)_{\in\emptyset}P(t)$

This sentence uses an abbreviation (sub : $\in\emptyset$) meaning " belonging to the empty set"; fully developped, the sentence is :

> $\exists (t) ( t\in\emptyset\land P(t) )$.

This is a conjunction ( an "and" statement). And in order a conjuction to be true, both conjuncts have to be true. But the first conjunct is false in virtue of the definition of the empty set. So the whole conjunction has to be false.

- Now consider : $\forall (t)_{t\in\emptyset}P(t)$.

Fully developped, the sentence says:

> $\forall (t) ( t\in\emptyset\rightarrow P(t))$.

This sentence has to be true for any possible object $t$ you consider.

You can convince yourself of this by asking the question : is there a possible case in which the sentence could be false?

In order the sentence to be false, there should exist some object $t$ such that :

(1) $t\in\emptyset$ is true

***and***

(2) $P(t)$ is false.

But, ***in order (1) and (2) to be both true, (1), in particular, has to be true***... which is impossible. It is actually impossible that there exist some $t$ such that : $t\in\emptyset$.

Note :  $( A\rightarrow B) \equiv  \neg(A\land\neg B)$, which implies $\neg(A\rightarrow B) \equiv (A\land\neg B)$.

with symbol $\equiv$ meaning " is equivalent to" , symbol $\neg$ meaning " not", symbol $ \land$ meaning " and", and symbol $\rightarrow$ meaning " if...then".

Answer (score 0):

Any statement about the elements of the empty set is true. Hence you cannot conclude the existence of $t \in X$ from the truth of $P(t)$.

I like to say: The elements of the empty set have purple eyes. This is completely meaningless, however, true.